# Prove that there exists an undecidable complementary language

Tags: computability, turing-machines

Some language A ⊆ Σ∗
is called complementary if A ≤m complement of A. How can I show that there exists an
undecidable complementary language?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to explain concepts but just solving homework-style exercises for you is unlikely to really help.

Answer (score 2):

Take $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$ for simplicity.

Define $A \oplus B = 0A + 1B$. We have that $(A \oplus B)^c \equiv_m A^c \oplus B^c$ since they differ only by the empty string.

We now take any non recursive $A$, and consider $B = A \oplus A^c$. We have $A \leq_m B$, so $B$ is not recursive as well. Further, $B = A \oplus A^c \equiv_m (A^c \oplus A)^c \equiv_m (A \oplus A^c)^c = B^c$.

Comment: You might want to consider not doing people's homework for them.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I completely agree. I wasn't unsure about whether this was the case (and still am). Next time I will be more careful and provide a hint, only.

Comment: (Oops ... "I was unsure" --- please ignore the double negative above)

Comment: No worries -- I figured that was what you meant.